# speed up python3 np.where operation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I wonder that is there anyway to speed up python3/numpy's `np.where` operation? I have a minimal working example as follows:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 4, (768, 512, 512))
b = a.copy().astype(np.uint8)
c = b.copy()
print(a.shape)

ts = time()
a[a > 0] = 1
print(f'normalize in {time() - ts}s')

ts = time()
b[b > 0] = 1
print(f'normalize in {time() - ts}s')

ts = time()
c = np.where(c > 0, 1, c)
print(f'normalize in {time() - ts}s')
```

and the output is:

```
normalize in 0.9307191371917725s
normalize in 0.8891170024871826s
normalize in 0.7120938301086426s
```

as we can see that `np.where` gives the fastest result but it still pretty slow, as in my project I need to do such normalize operation about 50 times...

I am wondering that is there any faster way to do this? All I need is to convert any non-zero elements to 1. Thx!

Comment: You should use module `timeit` for profiling. `time()` is not intended for profiling and hard to get correct results, especially when a printout is involved. As it turns out, the first and the last expressions take about the same time, and the middle one is about 2.5 times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to accomplish your operation is to convert the matrix to the boolean datatype and then back to integer, especially if 8-bit integers are used:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

a = np.random.randint(0, 4, (768, 512, 512))
a_short = a.astype(np.uint8)

# Time to initialize   
%timeit b=a.copy()
201 ms ± 561 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit b=a.copy(); b=b.astype(bool).astype(int)
373 ms ± 347 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit b=a.copy(); b=np.where(b>0,1,b)
985 ms ± 150 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit b=a.copy(); b[b>0]=1
1.09 s ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Time to initialize    
%timeit b=a_short.copy()
26.7 ms ± 202 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The best of the best:

```
%timeit b=a_short.copy(); b=b.astype(bool).astype(np.uint8)
77.5 ms ± 47.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit b=a_short.copy(); b=np.where(b>0,1,b)
570 ms ± 476 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit b=a_short.copy();b[b>0]=1
844 ms ± 4.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `numexpr`:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

# for timing reference
a = np.random.randint(0, 4, (768, 512, 512))
%timeit a[a > 0] = 1
```

782 ms ± 9.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 4, (768, 512, 512))
%timeit a = ne.evaluate("where(a > 0, 1, a)")
```

254 ms ± 2.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

---

Or with `Numba`:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def n(x):
    for a in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
        for b in range(x.shape[1]):
            for c in range(x.shape[2]):
                if x[a,b,c]>0:
                    x[a,b,c]=1
    return x

# You should do this twice as it gets compiled first time through
%timeit c = n(a)
# Also, try re-assigning back on top of original, i.e. a=n(a)
```

113 ms ± 551 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)